# Django charfield compose default value

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I add a composed default value to a charfield?

Example

class Myclass(xxx):

```
type = models.ForeignKey(somewhere)
code = models.CharField(default=("current id of MyClass wich is autoincremented + type value"))
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you override the save method on your model.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self):
        super(Myclass,self).save()
        if not self.code:
            self.code = str(self.id) + str(self.type_id)
            self.save()
```

There is stuff you need to take care, like making the code a blank field, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should override the save method as Lakshman suggest, however, since this is the default and not blank=False, the code should be a little different:

```
Class MyClass(models.Model):
...
def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        self.code = str(self.id) + str(self.type_id)
    return super(Myclass,self).save())
```

Comment: How could you use self.id value in "if not self.id" case? Maybe you meant "if not self.code".

Comment: In Django 1.5 this appears to be broken.  I'm under the impression that the self.id field isn't populated until the new object is saved.  Hence the double save in Lakshman's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the post_save signal

```
from django.db.models import signals

class MyClass(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(somewhere)
    code = models.CharField(blank=True)

def set_code_post(instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.code = str(instance.id) + str(instance.type_id)
    instance.save()

signals.post_save.connect(set_code_post, sender=MyClass)
```

Or, for that matter, you could use a combination of pre_save and post_save signals to avoid running save() twice...

```
from django.db.models import signals

class MyClass(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(somewhere)
    code = models.CharField(blank=True)

def set_code_pre(instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, 'id'):
        instance.code = str(instance.id) + str(instance.type_id)

def set_code_post(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.code = str(instance.id) + str(instance.type_id)
        instance.save()

signals.pre_save.connect(set_code_pre, sender=MyClass)
signals.post_save.connect(set_code_post, sender=MyClass)
```