# GeoDjango create model with LineStringField with buffer

Tags: django, geodjango

I've created a street model which is made of segments. Each segment starts and ends with a Sign (model). I decided to use LineStringField for the street representation but In order to intersect future points with it, I want to add some buffer to it so when users come to street, I'll be able to tell if they're within this street within buffer.

```
class Segment(models.Model):
    starts_with_sign = models.ForeignKey(Sign)
    ends_with_sign = models.ForeignKey(Sign)
    seg = models.LineStringField()

class Street(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_one_way = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    is_avenue = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    has_public_transportation_lane = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    parking_area = models.ForeignKey(Area) # for cities with parking areas
    segments = models.ForeignKey
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My questions are:

1. How do I add this buffer to the LineStringField?
2. How do I assign Signs (points) to the
   LineStringField?
3. With a given coordinate, how do I query for the
   segment which the point is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging and rethinking all day long I've come up with some implementation ideas:

1. Instead of adding buffer to each LineString which will make it a
   Polygon (waste of data space?) and perform a point search for a relevant Polygon with a
   given Point, after going over again on [PostGIS ST_Buffer's docs](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html)
   (`Geom.buffer` on `GeoDjango`) I understood a better (and faster) use for future queries would be
   with [PostGIS ST_DWithin](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html) ( `<field>__<distance
   lookup>=(<geometry>, <distance value>[, 'spheroid'])` on
   [GeoDjango GeoQuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/)) and by that storing a Segment or street in this case would be with LineString.
2. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012814/django-charfield-compose-default-value) post, I've come up with this piece of code:

   ```
   class Sign(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
       gps_point = models.PointField()
       objects = models.GeoManager()

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name

   class Segment(models.Model):
       start_sign = models.ForeignKey(Sign, related_name='seg_start')
       end_sign = models.ForeignKey(Sign, related_name='seg_end')
       line = models.LineStringField(blank=True, null=True)
       objects = models.GeoManager()

       def save(self):
           super(Segment,self).save()
           if not self.line and self.start_sign and self.end_sign:
               self.line = LineString(self.start_sign.gps_point,self.end_sign.gps_point)
               self.save()
   ```

   so by overriding `save()` I could assign `LineString(self.start_sign.gps_point,self.end_sign.gps_point)` to `LineStringField` once save is done.
   Now all I have to deal with is assigning a start sign for segment's start point and end sign for segment's ending and the LineString object will be created for me :)
3. So now I can just filter out the relevant street/segment just by `Segment.objects.filter(line__distance_lte=(Point(lat,lon),D(m=required_distance))`.

Cheers